# java project programming removing string

Tags: java

This code   you can add item number and quantity and remove quantity.Item number is a string and the quantity is a integer value. My question is how do i remove a string which is the item number.Like if you scroll all the way to the bottom you see the method RemoveQuanitity and thats a integer. But i want to know if i can make a method to remove the item number which is a string. I hope this makes sense.

Brief description: of what the program does you can assign an item with the number of quantity so example item 1 quantity 10. So you can remove decrease the quantity. My question is how to remove the item number which is a string, which is the part i am stuck at do i have to make a method or a constructor?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
// Define a class for inventory objects
class InventoryObj{

    // Parameters for an Inventory object
    private String itemNumber;
    private int qty;    
    String object;

    // Define a static array list of Inventory objects
    static List<InventoryObj> Records = new ArrayList<InventoryObj>();

    //public InventoryObj(String objects) {
        //this.object = objects;
    //}

    // Constructor for Inventory objects
    InventoryObj(String arg1, int arg2) {
        itemNumber = arg1;
        qty = arg2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return itemNumber + "\t" + qty + "\n";
    }

    public String getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int arg) {
        qty = arg;
    }
}

public class Project_Manufacturing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Inventory Simulator!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response;
        do {
            PrintMenu();
            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            // Note: JRE 7 required for switching using a string
            switch (response) {
            case "AI":
                System.out.print
                    ("Enter item number and quantity to add to inventory: ");
                AddInventory(input.next(), input.nextInt());

                PrintInventoryReport();
                break;

            case "SR":
                System.out.print
                    ("Enter customer name, item number and quantity to ship: ");
                ShippingRequest(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextInt());
                PrintInventoryReport();
                break;

            case "PI":
                PrintInventoryReport();

                break;
            case "RQ":
                System.out.print
                    (" item number and quantity t: ");
                RemoveQuantity( input.next(), input.nextInt());
                PrintInventoryReport();
                break;

            case "EX":
                System.out.println("Exiting the Inventory Simulator");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Code, try again.");
            }
        } while (!response.equals("EX"));
        input.close();
    }

    private static void ShippingRequest(String customer, String item, int qty) {
        //System.out.printf("Received an order for %d of item %s for shipment to %s \n",qty, item, customer);
        boolean found = false;
        for (InventoryObj each : InventoryObj.Records)

            // Check if the item is in inventory
            if (each.getItemNumber().equals(item)) {
             found = true;
             System.out.printf("Received an order for %d of item %s for shipment to %s \n",qty, item, customer);
                each.setQty(each.getQty() - qty);
                found = true;
                if(each.getQty() < qty){
                    found = false;
            System.out.println("No sufficient items in the Inventory");
            }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println("Item not found");
    }


        //if( qty == 0) {
            //qty = 0;
            //}
        //System.out.println("Error");

    }

    // Add to the inventory
    static void AddInventory(String item, int qty) {
        // Look for the item in the Inventory list
        boolean found = false;
        for (InventoryObj each : InventoryObj.Records)

            // Check if the item is in inventory
            if (each.getItemNumber().equals(item)) {
                // Add the quantity made to the inventory
                each.setQty(each.getQty() + qty);
                found = true;
            }
        if (!found)
            // If item not found in inventory, add an inventory record
            InventoryObj.Records.add(new InventoryObj(item, qty));
    }

    static void RemoveQuantity(String item, int qty) {
        // Look for the item in the Inventory list
        boolean found = false;
        for (InventoryObj each : InventoryObj.Records)

        if (each.getItemNumber().equals(item)) {
             found = true;
         System.out.println("Item"+ qty + "removed from the inventory");
            each.setQty(each.getQty() - qty);
            found = true;
            if(each.getQty() > qty){
                found = false;
        System.out.println("No sufficient items in the Inventory");
        }
    if (!found)
        System.out.println("Item not found");
        }


}
    // Print an inventory report
    static void PrintInventoryReport() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Inventory Report");
        System.out.println("Item\tQuantity");
        for (InventoryObj each : InventoryObj.Records)
            System.out.print(each);
    }

    // Print a menu of commands
    static void PrintMenu() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PI: Print Inventory Report");
        System.out.println("AI: Add to Inventory");
        System.out.println("SR: Shipping Request (TBC)");
        System.out.println("RI: Remove an Item from Inventory (TBD)");
        System.out.println("RQ: Remove a Quantity of an Item from Inventory (TBD)");
        System.out.println("EX: Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter one of the codes above: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with the code in terms of efficiency, logic, etc. but I'll overlook them and answer the question.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to remove a record from the inventory. Similar to how you added an item to the inventory, you can remove it by calling the remove function on the list object passing in the reference or index of the item/record to be remove.

```
/* The each variable here is a reference to the InventoryObj object that is to be removed. 
   I used each because that is what you have been calling it in your program. */
InventoryObj.Records.remove(each);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should remember that Java is case sensitive and routines (methods/functions) should always start with lower case letter except if the method is a constructor.

If I understand you right, you waht to just edit the itemNumber. Your itemNumber field is private, that means that other objects cannot access it directly. If you want to manipulate the field from the outside of the InventoryObj object, first you will need to create a public method inside the InventoryObj, which will be accessible from outside of the InventoryObj itself. For example this method should be placed inside the InventoryObj:

```
public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber){
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
}
```

This method is called a "setter" and you can find tons of tutorials on "encapsulation" and "getter" and "setter" methods online.

Only then, if you are able to manipulate the private field (your itemNumber is private remember) from within your InventoryObj, you can create another method in your class Project_Manufacturing (or wherever you like, the method is public so you can call it from any part of your application) to remove/alter the itemNumber.  For instance this method would be placed in your Project_Manufacturing class:

```
public void removeItemNumber(){
   // Look for the item in the Inventory list
        boolean found = false;
        for (InventoryObj each : InventoryObj.Records)

            // Check if the item is in inventory
            if (each.getItemNumber().equals(item)) {
                // Alter the itemNumber
                each.setItemNumber("");
                found = true;
            }
        if (!found)
            // If item not found in inventory, add an inventory record
            InventoryObj.Records.add(new InventoryObj(item, qty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 8, you can use [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
boolean remove(String item) {
    return InventoryObj.Records.removeIf(r -> r.getItemNumber().equals(item));
}
```